# Add an image (or other resources) to a Mac or iOS Framework

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

Let's say I have an existing iOS or Mac Framework that we'll call Test.framework. This framework has compiled and linked successfully (a trick was done to lipo both i386 and armv6/7 archs for the iOS part) and is working perfectly fine.

Now I want to add an image to it let's call it '`test.png`'. I have copied it into the Resources folder of my framework so that I have the following structure:

```
ls Test.framework

- Headers -> Versions/Current/Headers
- Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
- Test -> Versions/Current/Test
- Versions 

ls Test.framework/Resources

- Info.plist
- test.png
```

Yet when I create a project using my framework I cannot access that image.

I've tried:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]
[UIImage imageNamed:@"Test.framework/test.png"]
[UIImage imageNamed:@"Test.framework/Resources/test.png"]
```

But nothing worked out that always gave me back a `nil` object.

Any ideas ?

**EDIT**

After much further investigation it seems what I am trying to accomplish can't be done on iOS. The reason is that the final application bundle (the .app) doesn't copy the private frameworks where applications compiled for Mac OS will.

This is further detailed in the [iOS Bundle Structures documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW28).

Thanks to Rob Keniger and xuzhe for their appreciated help. I will credit xuzhe for the answer as it is actually the most appropriate answer to my original problem (even though Rob comment made me dig quite deeper into the issue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "imageNamed:" method is only for images in your App bundle. You should use

```
[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

instead.

About the path, since I am not sure if the "Test.Framework" is in you App bundle, I am not able to give you a sample code. But if it dose, the code below should work:

```
NSString* path = [Nsstring stringWithFormat:@"%@/Test.framework/Resources/test.png", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
```

Comment: saying that 'The "imageNamed:" method is only for images in your App bundle' is not entirely true. If I add a bundle (say test.bundle) to my project and this bundle has test.png in it then [UIImage imageNamed:@"test/test.png"] will work nicely.

Comment: however your solution is interesting, but I do not have the framework bundled into my application (it can be installed in the commond frameworks folders)

Comment: @apouche If your are adding a bundle in your App bundle and then call `[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.bundle/test.png"];` it's OK because the test.bundle is also in the main bundle. If it's not, I doubt the "imageNamed:" can find it.

Comment: @appouche I see, the framework is out of your App. Since on iOS, there is no way to get something outside the sandbox, so you have to include the framework into your App bundle. But in Mac OS X, it's your responsibility to find out what's the actually path of your framework, and then use it as the path var to get your image.

Comment: arf that's pretty annoying. The Apple documentation clearly says that one of the things you can do with frameworks is add resources to them but they don't say how you access them afterwards... I'm still sure there is a way but it's probably only blind hope

Comment: thanks for your help, what i wanted to accomplish can't be done on iOS please refer to my edit if you want more information

Answer (score 3):

You can get the bundle for a particular class using `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[SomeClass class]]`. All you need to do is pass in a class that's defined in the framework and you'll have a reference to the framework's bundle.

You can then ask the bundle for the path to the image using the `pathForResource:ofType:` method of `NSBundle`, and then use the `initWithContentsOfFile:` method of `NSImage` to create your image.

Note that you should never hard-code paths. Ever. There are many different functions and methods for obtaining paths to resources, you never need to hard-code them.

Comment: this is quite smart but unfortunately it didn't really give the expected results. when I did `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[SomeClass class]]` it gave me back the exact same object as the main bundle. The reason is that all classes used from my Test.framework were added to the final project binary and not 'copied' into the final .app path. So in the end the resources are skipped :(

Comment: thanks for your help, what i wanted to accomplish can't be done on iOS please refer to my edit if you want more information